# how to get complete details of user from parse cloud and use those in background jobs function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

This is my code I am getting number of users and objects as "result [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" but I want to fetch the details of each object and want to use those details Please help me how to fetch the user details

```js
Parse.Cloud.job("findAll", function(request, status) {

// var comments= Parse.Cloud.run("makeCall",{success: function(object) {response.success(object);}});
 Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()
  var result = [];

  var processCallback = function(res) {
    result = result.concat(res);
    if (res.length === 1000) {
      process(res[res.length-1].id);
      return;
    }

    // do something about the result, result is all the object you needed.
    //status.success("final length " + result.length);
    //status.success("final result " + result);
  }
  var process = function(skip) {

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    if (skip) {
      console.log("in if");
      query.greaterThan("objectId", skip);
    }
    query.limit(1000);
    //query.contains("objectId",request.params.objectId);
    query.find().then(function querySuccess(res) {
      processCallback(res);
      status.success("result " + res('username'));
      
    }, function queryFailed(reason) {
      status.error("query unsuccessful, length of result " + result.length + ", error:" + error.code + " " + error.message);
      
    });
  }
  process(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `status.success("result " + res('username'));` is concatenating a string with an object, which will call `toString()` on the object before the concatenation can be done.

If you want to pass a string to `success`, serialize the object to JSON:

```
status.success("result " + JSON.stringify(res('username')));
```

If you want to pass the result object to `success`, just pass the object without the string concatenation:

```
status.success(res('username'));
```

Below is a working example to illustrate the difference among the three approaches.

```js
var result = {
  color: 'blue',
  shape: 'square'
};

//String concatenation with object
log('Result ' + result);

//String concatenation with JSON
log('Result ' + JSON.stringify(result));

//Object
log(result);

//Log function for demonstration purposes
function log (o) {
  var e = document.createElement('pre');
  e.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(o, null, '  ');
  document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I tried both the lines and check but in job status tab I am getting error as TypeError: object is not a function at processCallback

Comment: @uttamraj That is a different issue from the one you described in the question. Something in your code that you are trying to execute is not a function. Perhaps `status.success` or `status.error` are not functions?

Comment: I am IOS developer and I am beginner to parse.so, let me explain you in brief I have three users in User class with phone number,email address and BGactive as a columns.So I want to fetch all the users details in  Parse.Cloud.job function and from there depending on some condition I want to call another method which is in same .js file and I will call that function for every 1 min .this is my requirement

Comment: and when I run your code i got the result as "Result [object Object]"
"Result {\"color\":\"blue\",\"shape\":\"square\"}"
{
  "color": "blue",
  "shape": "square"
}
so could please tell me how to access or fetch the details of color?

Comment: @ Drew Gaynorso: i used ur code but I am getting error as "ReferenceError: document is not defined at log"

Comment: @uttamraj You can't just copy-paste the entire snippet. The `log` function is strictly there for demonstration purposes. You wouldn't call that in your code. See the lines of code above the snippet for how this would apply to your particular case.

Comment: @uttamraj Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you (click the check mark under the voting buttons to the left of the answer).